# How to append two value inside jquery <ul id="mylist"> <li><a >First </a> <a>Second</a></li> </ul>

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists

How to  append two value inside jquery

First 
 Second

Comment: Please go read [ask], and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this multiple ways:

```
$('ul#mylist').append('<li><a>First</a></li><li><a>First</a></li>')`
```

OR

```
var html = '<li><a >First</a></li><li><a>Second</a></li>';
$('ul#mylist').append(html);
```

OR

```
$('ul#mylist').append('<li><a>First</a></li>');
$('ul#mylist').append('<li><a>Second</a></li>');
```

And some other ways as well...

Comment: we need  this format <ul><li><a >First</a><a>Second</a></li></ul>  inside li contain two different value

Comment: then it's could to be something like this `$('ul#mylist').append('<li><a>First</a><a>First</a></li>')`

Comment: $('ul#mylist').append('<li><a>First</a><a>First</a></li>') not like that ,i need  <li><a>First value</a><a>second value</a></li> dynamically using json data append ,

Comment: then tell us more about the JSON that is used, it might help

Comment: $('ul#mylist').append('<li><a>First</a><a>First</a></li>') not like that ,i need <li><a>First value</a><a>second value</a></li> dynamically using json data append  ,any one can pls help me this problem